# Parameters for comparison of Salsa, HC-128 and SOSEMANUK

Tags: cryptanalysis, stream-cipher, salsa20

I am doing my final project of computer science and I need some help.

I understand how Salsa works, but I don't have the same knowledge of HC-128 and SOSEMANUK. I have to do a table with the advantages and disadvantages of each one.

What parameters can I compare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HC-128 and SOSEMANUK are two stream ciphers that were studied by the "eSTREAM" project. A bunch of candidates were evaluated, and the "best" (in some way) were kept in the final portfolio.

From [the eSTREAM project page](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/), you will find a lot of information on these algorithms, including full specification, reference code, test vectors, and design descriptions. There are also links to benchmarks.

The point of making you write a table that compares parameters for these algorithms is, indeed, to have you read these documents and *understand* what parameters are relevant. Ideally, you would go beyond what is already documented to take into account some newer research (e.g. while SOSEMANUK is really fast in software, the natural implementation will use a lookup table with state-dependent addresses, which is a bad thing with regards to side-channel attacks; a fair assessment of the algorithms should discuss such things).

Comment: thanks thomas, i dont know about that webpage. Its very helpfull

Comment: @RobertNN If the answer fits your needs, please don't forget to accept it be clicking the checkmark (✓) left of the answer. That way, the system and other users know your question has been answered to your satisfaction. Thanks in advance…